# AudioTrack how to make pause

Tags: android, button, audio, audio-player

I'm trying make pause and resume in my AudioRecorder. To play sound I use AudioTrack.

```java
public void startPlay(int playFrequency) {
...
audioTrack.play();
short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];
while (isPlaying) {
for (int i = 0;i < bufferSize; i++) {
try {
short s = dataIS.readShort();
buffer[i] = s;
}catch (EOFException eofe){isPlaying = false;}]
audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize); }
audioTrack.stop();
dataIS.close();}
```

I tried use `audioTrack.pause()` and again play but it didn't work.

```java
public void Pause(){
isPlaying=false;
audioTruck.pause() }
```

And here it's OK I click pause button, player stop played sound but when I click resmue/play nothing happened no resume, no sound.

```
public void Resume(){
isPlaying=true;
audioTruck.play(); i tried too startPlay();}
```

Comment: Check your varialble name!! audioTruck and audioTrack ..

Comment: With variable is everything ok, but i don't know how to stop "while" when i click pause and how to resume when i klick button resume. In variable it's my fault in code is everything ok :).